# webAPI with RESTful service in asp.net

Tags: c#-4.0

i just created a new project in web API in VS 2013 with asp.net . i want to  create a web service to retrieve data from the client  server, which is using REST service , when enter a product code . can you please give me the link for the source code  i have to generate and the 
corresponding class files .

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial link or reference here or want to get ready-made code? First try something and then while coding if you face any issue, ask it specifically.

Comment: i created the c product model class and corresponding Controller class. but am get confused to write the code in controller class. i don't know  the code  for retrieving data  from client  and store in a dataset .Please help .am very new to this concept

Comment: I am still not clear. What you are explaining is MVC pattern [So considering it as ASP.NET MVC application]. But your title says about webAPI and RESTful service.

Comment: it is web API application in asp.net VS 2013 . it support MVC structure . i want to create a service application in web APi.the client server using REST services . i want to get data from that client server using web API service